# System.InvalidProgramException: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program'

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core-3.1

In very specific situations, such as when I implement the injection of two dependencies together, the exception "System.InvalidProgramException: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.'" occurs.

Our system is made in .NET Core 3.1 with MongoDriver to use MongoDB.
When I keep only one of the two dependencies, the error doesn't happen. Interestingly, in other AppServices classes, there are these same dependency injections together and the error doesn't occur either.

[image: Example of dependency injection with problem]

My biggest problem is that the exception details don't show me relevant information that could help identify the root cause of the problem to solve it.

Please help me to identify the root cause of the error.

This exception occurs **only from the third call/execution of some specific controller APIs**, with the following detailed message:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: close
Content-Length: 362
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: _gcl_au=1.1.1728041573.1668795993; _ga=GA1.1.1378695825.1668795993; intercom-id-bp6b4t1q=377c2c7a-43e8-47ef-a44e-3059604756cd; intercom-device-id-bp6b4t1q=c5417705-ee5b-44ff-9502-983c21421f99; intercom-session-bp6b4t1q=; _ga_WFJ98H6EZX=GS1.1.1675689004.39.1.1675689609.60.0.0
Host: localhost:44342
Referer: https://localhost:44342/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
origin: https://localhost:44342
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

I'm updated package "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection", etc.

Comment: If you have `code optimization` turn on in c#, try to turn that off.

Comment: For debug mode, I already have disabled code optimization, but I have the same exception in output.